# Get FileName or Path when using Print Dialog to print with "Microsoft Print To Pdf"

Tags: c#, wpf

I am printing my canvas with **Print Dialog** and then saving it into PDF with Microsoft Print to PDF in my **WPF/C#** application. Now I am having 2 issues here:

1. When i am putting comma(,) into file name then its not saving any file and also not giving any error code or message.
2. Now i want to check if user has entered comma(,) in file name so i can show error message from my code but I am not able to get file name or path which user has selected.

Kindly provide me some fix so i can save file which is having comma(,) in its name or i can check file name or path from Print Dialog so i can show custom message.

Below is my function which i am using

```
 public void RenderCanvasImage(int maxRight, int maxBottom, Canvas surface, Transform transform)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(maxRight, maxBottom, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderBitmap.Render(surface);
            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            {
                return;
            }

            Grid grid = new Grid();
            Image myImage = new Image();
            myImage.Source = renderBitmap;
            myImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            grid.Children.Add(myImage);
            Grid.SetColumn(myImage, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(myImage, 1);

            grid.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
            grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), grid.DesiredSize));
            dialog.PrintVisual(grid, "My Canvas");

            surface.LayoutTransform = transform;
        }
```

Thanks in Advance